# Как перевести XSD к XML?

Tags: xml, xsd

Не могу разобраться с XSD  схемой хотя вроде бы все как по учебнику.

```
<xs:complexType name="getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest" type="tns:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest" form="qualified"
minOccurs="0"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:complexType name="tnEODICOBJECTSRequest">
<xs:sequence>
<xs:element name="objectId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Id объекта</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="classId" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Id класса (спраочника)</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
<xs:element name="objectKod" type="xs:int" nillable="true">
<xs:annotation>
<xs:documentation>Код символьный</xs:documentation>
</xs:annotation>
</xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>
```

Мой вариант XML

```
<ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS xmlns:ns0="http://service.siw.getcode.go/">
    <ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
        <ns0:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest>     
           <objectId>574</objectId>     
           <classId>4000</classId>
           </ns0:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest>         
     </ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
</ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS>
```

Мой вариант вызывает ошибку. Подскажите пожалуйста что не так?
Немного не понятно тут

> <xs:element name="TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest"
> type="tns:tnEODICOBJECTSRequest" form="qualified"

[Схема](https://dropmefiles.com/tJL6n)

Comment: Какую ошибку вызывает? Всегда приводите текст ошибок.

Comment: `<error>
<errorCode value="100"/>
<errorMessage value="ORA-19112: error raised during evaluation: can not get xquery string"/>
<errorStatusCode value="400"/>
</error>]]></Text>
` Ошибка. Только Я понять не могу в чем дело. Вроде все как по схеме

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: schema]

Решение:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <!-- Created with Liquid Studio 2021 (https://www.liquid-technologies.com) -->
  <tns:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS xmlns:tns="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/" 
                            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                            xsi:schemaLocation="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/ SO_67668466.xsd">
     <tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
        <objectId>-4486</objectId>
        <classId>2000</classId>
        <objectKod>-4247</objectKod>
        <objectKodstr>string</objectKodstr>
        <objectVname>string</objectVname>
        <objectName>string</objectName>
        <objectSname>string</objectSname>
        <refer>2060</refer>
        <s1>string</s1>
        <i1>-475</i1>
        <komm>string</komm>
        <corTip>string</corTip>
        <dateNd>2001-01-15T04:53:04.70</dateNd>
        <dateKd>2011-10-07T16:16:02.20</dateKd>
        <corTime>1993-10-18T10:43:28.61</corTime>
        <operId>-3192</operId>
        <dorNsi>string</dorNsi>
     </tns:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
  </tns:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS
```

Answer (score 0):

Элемент с именем `tnEODICOBJECTSRequest` не определён в показанной схеме.

В соответствии с вашей схемой, внутри элемента `TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest` должна быть последовательность из элементов `objectId`, `classId`, `objectKod`.

То есть XML может выглядеть так:

```
<ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS xmlns:ns0="http://service.siw.getcode.go/">
  <ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
    <ns0:objectId>574</ns0:objectId>
    <ns0:classId>4000</ns0:classId>
    <ns0:objectKod>0</ns0:objectKod>
  </ns0:TN_EO_DIC_OBJECTSRequest>
</ns0:getTN_EO_DIC_OBJECTS>
```

Comment: Я прикрепил схему выше, может поможет для понимания